# Reverse Integer number without duplicate digit in java

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity

My objective is to reverse integer number without duplicate digit in Java
How do I improve the complexity of code or is there a good/standard algorithm present?

Incase of duplicate digit, it should preserve last digit

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = -19890;
    System.out.println(reverseNumberWithoutDuplicate(n));
}

public static int reverseNumberWithoutDuplicate(int number) {
    boolean isNegative = (number < 0);
    number = isNegative ? number * -1 : number;

    Set<Character> lookup = new HashSet<>();

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    char[] digits = String.valueOf(number).toCharArray();
    for (int i = digits.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        if (lookup.contains(digits[i])) {
            continue;
        }
        sb.append(digits[i]);
        lookup.add(digits[i]);
    }
    return isNegative ? Integer.parseInt(sb.toString()) * -1 : Integer.parseInt(sb.toString());
}
```

**Expected output: -981**

Comment: Can you give what you want the output to be? For `-19890` do you want `981` or `891`?

Comment: What do you mean "without duplicate number"?

Comment: one digit should come once.

Comment: i guess if the lookup hashset keeps the characters in order as they are added you could use the hash set without needing your StringBuffer sb

Comment: @SaurabhKhare can you please update your question with that information. For instance, say that you mean the output is **not** the input in reverse, but specifically the input reversed *after* duplicate removal, and explain how you need that to work: preserve first one? preserve last one? Remove all? what happens with 172737 for instance? does it become 123, 1723, 1273, or 1237 before reversing?

Comment: updated, It should preserve last one from original number.

Comment: What is the expected answer for 1020: 21 or 210?

Comment: Hmm what do you mean with 'improve complexity' ? if you mean the runtime complexity ( O-calcule) your code should be near O(n) where n is the input's length. Or do you mean improve the code readabillity (like removing the `continue` part and instead do a `if(!lookup.contains(digits[i]))[sb.append(...); ...}` . Or do you want to use as view classes as possible (for example exchange the character set with a boolean array of size 10)? Edit: ok I understand what you wanted by Joop's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The complexity is fine. Though it can be optimized.

Using StringBuilder is better than the older StringBuffer, which has unneeded overhead (for thread-safeness).

Then the data can remain numerical, and for the ten possible digits a BitSet is just fine.

```
public static int reverseNumberWithoutDuplicate(int number) {
    if (number == Integer.MIN_VALUE) {
        // -2147483648 is a special case, not negatable.
        return -8463712;
    }
    boolean isNegative = number < 0;
    number = isNegative ? -number : number;

    BitSet usedDigits = new BitSet(10);
    int reversedNumber = 0;
    while (number != 0) {
        int digit = number % 10;
        number /= 10;
        if (!usedDigits.get(digit)) {
            usedDigits.set(digit);
            reversedNumber = 10 * reversedNumber + digit;
        }
    }
    return isNegative ? -reversedNumber : reversedNumber;
}
```

Comment: Input: Integer.MIN_VALUE

Comment: @Durandal (I knew it then) but actually the full-domain solution is not that hard, so I apologise, and added it - as special case, in order not to deal with negative modulos and such.

Answer (score 5):

Let's build a solution step-by step. The following function reverses digits of the positive number.

```
int reverseNumber(int number) {
    int answer = 0;
    for (int n = number; n != 0; n /= 10) {
        // Digits are taken from least significant to most significant
        int digit = n % 10; 
        // And added the other way round
        answer = answer * 10 + digit;
    }
    return answer;
}
```

This code could be easily adapted to work with negative numbers to:

```
int reverseNumber(int number) {
    if (number < 0) {
        return -reverseNumber(-number);
    }
    // The rest is the same
```

Our next target -- skip duplicate digits. We will track a list of the already seen digits in the `boolean[] seen`.

```
private static int reverseNumberWithoutDuplicate(int number) {
    if (number < 0) {
        return -reverseNumberWithoutDuplicate(-number);
    }

    boolean[] seen = new boolean[10];
    int answer = 0;
    for (int n = number; n != 0; n /= 10) {
        int digit = n % 10;            
        if (!seen[digit]) {
            seen[digit] = true;
            answer = answer * 10 + digit;
        }
    }
    return answer;
}
```